# Flutter run -d all Won't start chrome

Tags: flutter

`flutter run -d all` will start the application on android and iOS Simulators but won't start chrome.

Any Ideas?

Here is my `flutter doctor` output if that matters:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.12.13+hotfix.6, on Mac OS X 10.15.1 19B88, locale de-DE)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.2.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[!] Android Studio
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    ✗ Android Studio not found at /Applications/Android/Contents
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.2.3)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.36.1)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: is flutter run -d chrome working?

Comment: @YudhishthirSingh yes

Answer (score 1):

I think this is intended behavior, the same way that if you type `flutter run -d all` when no other device than Chrome and the web server are available, it outputs `No devices found`. I guess it's because the web support is still experimental. The only way is `flutter run -d chrome`.

Comment: I'm trying to have all devices (iOS, android and web) run at the same time in debug, so `flutter run -d chrome` won't help me here

Comment: I understand, my point is that you can't. Being able to specify multiple specific devices would be great for this, but unfortunately it's not the case. They might provide a solution before the web support lands in the stable channel.